# how to set ajax response in <spring:message code=>

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I'm trying to set data value which is error code `(eg: 100-101)` in a code field of `spring:message`

But I'm getting

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code '" + $(data) + "' for locale 'en_US'.

I'm not able to fetch data value, can anyone help me with this?

```
success: function(data, status){
    if(data != 'undefined' && status == 'success'){
        $("#xxx_form").replaceWith(<div class='ap-container'><h4 class='ap-label ap-text-brown'><spring:message code='" + $(data) + "'/></h4></div>);
```

Comment: First observation: The `replaceWith()` argument isn't enclosed by quotes like it should. You'll have to check about escaping the other quotes within it... Then, I don't know what is your `<spring:...>` tag... Is it for use with an unmentionned plugin ?

Comment: When the ajax success callback triggers... It's useless to check for `status == 'success'`. It always will be `true`.

Comment: All the quotes are closed correctly, it was missed during copy paste, if I replace $(data) with exact key in my properties file, for example <spring:message code='error.some.code'/> it works fine and shows me the message associated with it like in my messages.properties I have error.some.code=some message, it will show 'some message' but when I try to read code from ajax response, it is failing.

Comment: Ok then Let's try to nail down this... How is your `data` structured ? Try `+ data +` instead of `+ $(data) +`. Or `+ data.error +`. Because, clearly, `$(data)` doesn't referer to anything.

Comment: none of them are working for me, here is the exact line : '$("#login_form").replaceWith("<div class='ap-container'><h4 class='ap-label ap-text-brown'><spring:message code='" + data + "'/></h4></div>");' and data has value : 100-104 which is mapped to some message in messages.properties file

Comment: Ok a test! ;) Try: `console.log( JSON.stringify(data) )`. Comment out the rest of your `success` handler. Run and copy-paste the console log result here.

Comment: "100-107" this what I got in console, my spring controller only returns error codes.

Comment: What is "spring controller"?